# How to convert Unmanaged<CFString> to NSString?

Tags: ios, swift, cfstring

My application is dealing with contacts data.

The phone label is retrieved as following

```
let locPhoneLabel : NSString = (ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, numberIndex) != nil) ? ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, numberIndex).takeUnretainedValue() as CFStringRef : ""

let phoneLabel:Unmanaged<CFString> = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(locPhoneLabel)
```

I don't know how to convert phoneLabel to NSString?

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
let phoneLabel = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(locPhoneLabel)
.takeRetainedValue() as? NSString
```

There is a great post here if you are interested.[Unmanaged from NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/unmanaged/).

Answer (score 0):

For me it only helped:

```
let locLabel : CFStringRef = (ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i) != nil) ? (ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i).takeUnretainedValue()) as CFStringRef : ""
let noteForThisNumber = String (ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(locLabel).takeRetainedValue())
```